# Last elseif statement does not work in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

On the homepage of the website, I do a check query when I get pictures of post cards from the database. I don't have very deep algorithms and knowledge of PHP, but for now it seemed to handle.

There are two options when uploading images to post either image url or upload file. When I get the data from the data file with the variable before the end of the path is set into the SRC, so the picture is on the server if there is a check on the server if the second stage of the URL is passed to another site where the image is taken. If I don't have data in mysql, I want the img tag to show a fixed image but I couldn't do it somehow. It doesn't happen when you do "Elseif () {}" or "else". If you pass the code to the end of the code and add only a fixed picture is taken. but it naturally takes the picture below. Outside the Elseif structure. Now how do I apply a fixed image if the image url doesn't exist? Thank you for your help.

I work Apache and PHP7.x by xampp. first two if statement has worked. but third does not work. I have tried just else and else if and elseif but none of them has not run.

[Image of Website's Last condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byIDB.jpg)

```
foreach ($homepage_contents as $key => $value) {
    ?>
        <div class="kutu shadow z-depth-1 rounded">


        <div style="position: relative;">
        <a id="content_title_link" href="index.php?url=icerik&id=<?=$value->icerik_id; ?>"> 

        <?php


    $fixed_img = '<img src="public/img/turkbayrak.JPG" alt="">';
    $dosya = "public/upload/$value->icerik_foto"; // ../upload/picture.jpg

    $img_url = "$value->icerik_foto"; //src="example.com/picture.jpg
    $img_url_length = var_export(mb_strlen($img_url,'utf8'));
    print_r($resim_url_length);                                 

    if (file_exists($dosya)) {
        echo '<img src="'.$dosya.'">';
    }elseif (strlen($img_url)>=2) {
        echo '<img src="'.$img_url.'">';
    }elseif(empty($img_url)||strlen($img_url)<2){

        echo 'Hello World';
        echo $fixed_img;

    }                                         

    if(strlen($img_url)<2){

        echo $fixed_img;
    }                                 

    ?>
```

I am expecting that the 3rd. elseif command will work. 
And if there is no url or image file it will use fixed-image that is descripted before.

!first card has no img from database in picture below link. so I set an fixed img but it does not work in elseif

Comment: You don't need to test both empty and strlen<2. If it's empty, the length is 0, which is less than 2.

Comment: In addition to this, don't output an element with a fixed ID (`content_title_link`) in a loop; you'll end up with duplicate IDs, which is invalid markup.

Comment: yes I know but I have tried to understand. When I remove them code also does not work. Thank you.

Comment: What is `$img_url_length = var_export(mb_strlen($img_url,'utf8'));` supposed to do? `var_export()` prints its argument, it doesn't return anything useful unless the second argument is `true`.

Comment: That should just be `$img_url_length = mb_strlen($img_url,'utf8');` without `var_export`.

Comment: You can also replace the last `elseif` by simply `else` since you check for `>=2` right before, if that fails it means it's `<2`

Comment: But you never use the variable `$img_url_length`. Did you mean to use that here: `print_r($resim_url_length);`?

Comment: I have used ` $img_url_length` before but it does not work, too. I used it by removing var_export, too. Now it is not used in code.

Comment: The foreach loop seems to be unclosed

Comment: There are different html tags below of the " ?> " such as title categories etc. and I added to end of the html block.
       <?php       

      }
     }

     ?>
so the is no probelem about with foreach. Also if condition that is on end run for each card. $fixed_img run when I remove echo  '<img src="'.$img_url.'">;'  and  replace $fixed_img on second elseif statement.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem. Thanks for all supporters.  Firstly `$fixed_img = '<img src="public/img/turkbayrak.JPG" alt="">';` was wrong. I changed (') to (") so that `$fixed_img = "<img src='public/img/turkbayrak.JPG'>";`
Then, first I sent a query to database to get information about field is it empty or not. After that I applied before code.

```
        foreach ($homepage_contents as $key => $value) {
            ?>
                <div class="kutu shadow z-depth-1 rounded">


                <div style="position: relative;">
                <a id="content_title_link" href="index.php?url=icerik&id=<?=$value->icerik_id; ?>"> 

                <?php

      ////  [ " ' " was wrong at $fixed_img so ı have changed it to - " - ]
            $fixed_img = "<img src='public/img/turkbayrak.JPG'>"; 

            $dosya = "public/upload/$value->icerik_foto"; // ../upload/picture.jpg    
            $img_url = "$value->icerik_foto"; //src="example.com/picture.jpg

/// Firstly I sent a query to database in If Else Statement.

           if (empty($value->icerik_foto)) {
              echo $fixed_img;            
           }elseif (file_exists($dosya)) {
              echo "<img src='".$dosya."'>";
           }elseif (strlen($img_url)>=2) {
              echo "<img src='".$img_url."'>";
              print_r($img_url);
        }



            ?>
```